# Initial investment in sole proprietorship

Tags: stocks, income-tax, canada, ontario, sole-proprietorship

I've sole proprietorship business in Ontario. So far I've been doing web site and custom software development.

Then I open up an account for stock trading under same business name. And put some money in stock trading account from  business bank account.

I've not made a single penny from stock market. How do I report that initial investment in stock market? This is my first year for tax return for my business.

Answer (score 1):

The business and investment would be shown on separate parts of the tax return. (An exception to this is where an investment is related and part of your business, such as futures trading on business products)

On the business side of it, you would show the transfer to the stocks as a draw from the business, the amount transferred would then be the cost base of the investment.

For taxes, you only have to report gains or losses on investments.